# Inline constructors and One Definition Rule

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

Consider following source files
1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct X
{
    X()
    {
        cout << "1" << endl;
    }
};

void bar();

void foo()
{
    X x;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

2.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>

struct X
{
    X()
    {
        printf("2\n");
    }
};

void bar()
{
    X x;
}
```

Is program compiled from these files well-formed? What should be in it's output?

I've expected linker error due to violation of One Definition Rule or output "1 2". However it prints out "1 1" when compiled with g++ 3.4 and VC 8.0.
How this can be explained?

Comment: If I use `[[gnu::noinline]]` for both with *clang 3.6.1* then output is 1 1 without respecting to order of file names specified to compiler and linker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does violate ODR (3.2) - specifically that you can have more than one definition of an inline function, but those definitions must be identical (3.2/5) - and leads to undefined behavior, so anything may happen and the compiler/linker is not required to diagnose that. The most likely reason why you see that behavior is that function calls are inlined and do not participate in linking, so no link error is emitted.

Comment: ODR does not apply to inline functions.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Description of how inline functions should behave is continuation of ODR description.

Comment: I tried to compile the compilation units to object files and then link them with both orders. The results was different so it looks for me that linker "throw away" additional definitions.

Comment: @Dmitriy Matveev: That's permissible. In fact anything is permissible when behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behaviour (with no required diagnostic) if inlined functions (such as your class constructor) have *different* definitions in different translation units.

Comment: Why it's UB ? Both translation unit sees different `X::X`; I agree that both are in same global scope. But then what can go wrong due to that ?

Comment: @iammilind: Since `X::X` is inline, all definitions of `X::X` in the whole program must be token-wise identical, otherwise the behavior is undefined. That's requirement of 3.2/5.